# Where is the configuration for Data/Services in Flash Builder saved?

Tags: zend-framework, flash-builder, amf, dataservice

I am trying to troubleshoot getting a Data/Service deployed to a live server in Flash Builder with an Air application.

I am using AMF/Zend but provided my own Php file called database.php. I'm trying to find somewhere in the code base where that is referenced, but I can't find anything, other than a link to my php file in the /services folder, which I have no idea how to change to linking to a remote file.